# How Can Get Address based on latitude and longitude?

Tags: iphone, json

I get Latitude And Longitude in iphone. but I want to find address based on that Latitude and Longitude. I have use Ios5. Please give me source Code to Find Address. I used this code
.m file

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:Coordinate2D];

[geocoder setDelegate:self];

[geocoder start]; // put in vievdidload


-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{    
    NSLog(@"The geocoder has returned: %@", [placemark country]);
}

-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

but it gives message- error.

Comment: Using Google GeoCoding API http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true and parsing json or xml with lat long which you want

Answer (score 0):

The one way is to use the google api to get location name and parse the xml. Hope it will help you

```
//Place below parser code where you are reading latlng and place your latlng in the url

NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false"]];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];

// Below are the delegates which will get you the exact address easyly

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{    
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"formatted_address"]){
    got = YES; //got is a BOOL
  }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  if(got){
    NSLog(@"the address is = %@",string);
  }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

}

//what we are doing is using xmlparser to parse the data which we get through the google map api copy above link and use in browser you will see the xml data brought
```

Comment: if you are using it then make sure to add NSXMLParserDelegate

Answer (score 0):

if You are using iOS5 then here is the code:-

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:10.0 longitude:10.0];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
  if(!error){
       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
       MKPlacemark *placemark1 = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithPlacemark:placemark];
       [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark1];   //mapView is object of MKMapView
     }
}];
```